# How to have multif-form application in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, multipage, data-sharing

I'm going to develop a shopping application which include several cascading forms.
The development platform is android 3.1. I got two problems.

1. what is a good strategy to have multiple forms? e.g. start new activity for each cascading form?
2. if using multiple activities is a good solution, how can share information between activities like shopping cart data (DB,Shared Class,...)?

I just jumped from C++ over here and I'm not that expert in visual environment application development.

Comment: read up on Android development. You can pass data using intents, broadcast receivers, calling classes, global variables, etc.  you can also use fragments to use one activity but swap out sections of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1) Use a different activity/layout for each form (things are easier and more organised).
2) Use an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) instance to store the global information.